# Reference for proof of symmetrical matrix-vector product: $(a - b)^T M (a - b) = a^T M a - 2b^T Ma + b^T M b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Given vectors $a$, $b$; and symmetrical square matrix $M$, we have this identity:

$$(a - b)^T M (a - b) = a^T M a - 2b^T Ma + b^T M b$$

Which is easy enough to prove:

$$(a - b)^T M (a - b) = a^TM(a-b) - b^TM(a - b) = a^TMa - a^TMb - b^TMa + b^TMb$$

$b^TMa$ is a scalar, so we can transpose it without altering it. Then, since $M=M^T$:

$$(b^TMa)^T = a^TM^Tb = a^TMb$$

Substituting this back into the second equation gives us the first statement.

What is a reference I can use to avoid writing this proof down? Or is it well-known enough to need no reference?

Comment: Why not cite this question?

Comment: That's salami slicing, giving myself citations for no reason :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to precede the result with the phrase "by inspection", meaning the reader can work out the proof themselves.

Comment: This phrase is just above "by intimidation" in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_jargon#Proof_techniques. 

I have never read this phrase, maybe because my field isn't math. This seems reasonable to me though; given the proof is easy and short.

Comment: @rhaps0dy I've seen/used "by inspection" a lot.